# How to move files from a server to the computer using perl

Tags: windows, perl

I want to move files from a server that my Windows computer is connected to, to the actual computer. I have tried the code on my mac and it works fine, so I suspect the problem has to do with the fact that the files I wish to move are on a server or perhaps with Windows (I am unfamiliar with this OS). It is important to me to be able to use `File::Find::Rule` because there are many subdirectories within subdirectories that need to be searched.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;
use File::Copy;

# directory where files live
# my $dir = "\\172.18\user\folder\folder2";

# directory where TextGrids will be moved to
my $outdir = "\users\lisa\desktop\test";

my @files;

@files = File::Find::Rule   -> file()
                             -> name("*_clean.TextGrid")
                             -> maxdepth()
                             -> in($dir);

foreach my $file (@files) {
    $file =~ /(.*\\)(.*)/;
    my $name = $2;
    copy("$file", "$outdir/$name") or die "Copy failed: $!";
    }
```

Edit: Ok, I've made some changes to the script below. But the strange thing is, that when I ask it to print each file, it gives me something like `\\172.18\user\folder\folder/255/file.txt`. I changed the regex to be `(.*\/)(.*)` and now the script works perfectly, though I don't know why!

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;
use File::Copy;

# directory where files live
my $dir = "\\\\172.18\\user\\folder\\folder2";

# directory where TextGrids will be moved to
my $outdir = "C:\\Users\\lisa\\desktop\\test";

my @files;

@files = File::Find::Rule   -> file()
                             -> name("*_clean.TextGrid")
                             -> maxdepth()
                             -> in($dir);

foreach my $file (@files) {
    print "$file\n";
    $file =~ /(.*\\)(.*)/;
    my $name = $2;
    copy("$file", "$outdir\\$name") or die "Copy failed: $!";
    }
```

Comment: Add the line `print $outdir` after you set `$outdir` for enlightenment. Then familiarize yourself with Perl's quoting rules and the difference between "double quotes" and 'single quotes'.

Comment: You have `use warnings` turned on, so Perl should alert you to an issue when you run this script.

Comment: $outdir is missing the drive letter. But it does start with a backslash. This may well not be a valid path at all. Have you tried adding the drive letter, for example C: as in `C:\users\lisa\desktop\text` ?

Comment: With rare exceptions, the win32 apis accept `/` as a filepath separator these days.  also, @bytepusher - paths beginning with `/` or `\\` are relative to the current drive, not directory (although you are correct that it's not *always* acceptable.  I suspect it's ok here, though.)

Comment: fair enough. It's been a while since I had to deal with Windows

Comment: Never assume any Windows API will support forward slashes for path handling unless explicitly documented.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck, Nonsense. The Windows API accepts `/` as a directory separator

Comment: @ikegami If you have proof, then I'll rescind my nonsensical statement :)

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck, You know how Perl has always let you use `/`, even on Windows? Well, it was never Perl. Perl simply passes the paths unchanged to the OS. `/` was a valid directory separator even 20 years ago when I started with Perl 5.6. A quick search found a comment that `/` has been supported since DOS 2.0!!! (Released in 1983, it the first version to support 5.25" floppy discs)  Do note that many command-line utilities treat "/" as the start of a switch. (e.g. Compare `dir c:/users` vs `dir "c:/users"`), but we're talking about the Windows API.

Comment: You're saying always, zzxyz says almost always, and neither of you provide literature to verify it. I don't question your collective experience -- I asked for somewhere that says it's okay to assume OS functionality being leveraged by Perl is from a WinAPI that is guaranteed to accept `/` as a path separator.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck, I wasn't speaking from experience, so your comment is moot. I researched it, and found it was accepted since DOS 2.0. I'm not about to check every single API call to see if one of them doesn't accept standard Windows paths. That would be silly. DOS and Windows considers `/` and `\ ` to be directory separators, and if zzxyz feels some Windows API calls don't accept Windows paths as a path, it's up to them to prove it.

Comment: Fair enough, @ikegami. It would have been nice to see some of the literature you researched that specified this, but I understand that's not always possible.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck, Apparently, DOS 2.0 was the first version of DOS that supported directories, so I was a bit misleading when I said "/" has only been supported since DOS 2.0. It would be more accurate to say that DOS and Windows have *always* supported "/"! Some [history](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2005/06/24/why-is-the-dos-path-character/) (Apparently, you used to be able to configure DOS to accept "-" instead of "/" for command-line utility switches.)

Comment: That's pretty cool! As you mentioned earlier, `/` won't work for all built-in CLIs unless you use double-quotes to wrap it. That sort of invalidates Larry's allusion that they should _all_ work, with his `notepad` example vs your `dir` example. However, not wrapping paths with quotes is a bit of a cardinal sin of generic automation (thanks, whitespace!), and as I don't recommend doing that I submit to your statement with a _slight_ modification; _double-quote-wrapped_ paths can use `/` safely :) Thanks for pulling that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit, the script works because the last directory separator in the string happens to be `/`, which is matched by the `\/` in the regular expression. Even though you had `\` in the input, the library you used to find the files added `/`s.

---

I have some suggestions:

1. You can avoid the need to escape (most) backslashes by using single quoted strings, unless you need the interpolation of the double quoted ones.

   Escaping backslashes is optional unless followed by a single quote or another backslash:

   ```
   my $outdir = '\users\lisa\desktop\test';
   ```

   but

   ```
   my $outdir = '\users\lisa\desktop\test\\';
   $outdir = '\users\lisa\desktop\test\\\'ere is a path';

   my $not_a_path = 'three backslashes\\\\\in between, all but the last need escaping';
   ```

   `'ere is a path` is the last element in that path.
2. If you're dealing with Windows, consider using `[\\/]` in place of directory separator in regular expressions. (Or `[\\\/]` if you absolutely must use `/` as regular expression delimiter.)

   Even if you have control over user input to only use `\` in paths, libraries you use will usually add `/`, so it's better to be prepared for a combination of both.

   ```
   $file =~ /(.*[\\\/])(.*)/;
   $file =~ m{(.*[\\/])(.*)};
   $file =~ m¤(.*[\\/])(.*)¤;
   ```

---

I also removed the superfluous quotes from around `$file` in the `copy()` call. Final result:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;
use File::Copy;

# directory where files live
my $dir = '\\172.18\user\folder\folder2';

# directory where TextGrids will be moved to
my $outdir = 'C:\Users\lisa\desktop\test';

my @files;

@files = File::Find::Rule   -> file()
                            -> name("*_clean.TextGrid")
                            -> maxdepth()
                            -> in($dir);

foreach my $file (@files) {
    print "$file\n";
    $file =~ /(.*[\\\/])(.*)/;
    my $name = $2;
    copy($file, "$outdir\\$name") or die "Copy failed: $!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = "\\172.18\user\folder\folder2";
print("$dir\n");

my $outdir = "\users\lisa\desktop\test";
print("$outdir\n");
```

outputs

```
Unrecognized escape \d passed through at a.pl line 7.
\172.18Ser?older?older2
Sersisadesktop  est
```

You need to escape your backslashes!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = "\\\\172.18\\user\\folder\\folder2";
print("$dir\n");

my $outdir = "\\users\\lisa\\desktop\\test";
print("$outdir\n");
```

Don't ignore warnings.